# Cannot Apply AOP in Glassfish

Tags: spring, glassfish-3, spring-aop

Hi need help in learniing basic spring .
i have a simple Aspect

```
@Aspect
public class HelloAspect {
static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(HelloAspect.class .getClass().getName());
@Before("execution(* *.*(..))")
public void logBefore(JoinPoint joinPoint) {
log.info("The method " + joinPoint.getSignature().getName()+ "() begins with "+Arrays.toString(joinPoint.getArgs()));
        }}
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema /tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd 
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd">
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />
<context:component-scan base-package="com"></context:component-scan>
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>
<context:annotation-config></context:annotation-config>
<context:load-time-weaver/>
<bean class="com.abhi.aop.HelloAspect"/>
<!--
Most controllers will use the ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping above, but
for the index controller we are using ParameterizableViewController, so we must
define an explicit mapping for it.
-->
<bean id="urlMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="index.htm">indexController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="viewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver"
      p:prefix="/WEB-INF/jsp/"
      p:suffix=".jsp" />
<!--
The index controller.
-->
<bean name="indexController"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.ParameterizableViewController"
      p:viewName="index" />
</beans>
```

application-context.xml is

I have a simple entity from derby table and controller mapping 
goal is to print logbefore  logger before every method.
but i get nothing on server after deployment log.

Comment: could you add a @Component annotation on your HelloAspect class too ?